# Maximization Minimization Algorithm: Bradley-Terry Ranking

Tags: summation, algorithms, convex-optimization, computational-mathematics, maximum-likelihood

With the help of exercices in my Machine Learning Class and course notes of Prof. Kenneth Lange available [there](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~aldous/Colloq/lange-talk.pdf), I'm trying to understand the derivation of the Maximization Minimization Algorithm with the example of Bradley-Terry Ranking:

Consider a sports league with $m$ teams. Assign team $i$ the skill level $\theta_i$. Bradley and Terry proposed the model
$$
P(i\text{ beats } j) = \frac{\theta_i}{\theta_i + \theta_j}
$$
To ensure that the skill levels are identifiable, we set $\theta_1= 1$. If $b_{i,j}$ is the number of times $i$ beats $j$, then the likelihood of the data is
$$
L(\theta) = \prod_{i,j}\Big(\frac{\theta_i}{\theta_i + \theta_j}\Big)^{b_{i.j}}
$$
Estimate $\theta$ by maximizing the log-likelihood $f(\theta) = \log L(\theta)$. Estimate the minorizing function $g(\theta|\theta^t)$ by using the supporting hyperplane. Maximize $g(\theta|\theta^t)$.
\newline
\newline
\textbf{Solution}
\newline
The log-likelihood function is
$$
f(\theta) = \sum_{i,j}b_{ij}(\log(\theta_i) - \log(\theta_i + \theta_j))
$$
We can use the inequality of the supporting hyperplane property
$$
h(y) \ge h(x) + \nabla h(x)^\top(y-x)
$$
For the convex function $h(x) = -\log(x)$ 
and we find
\begin{align*}
-\log(y) \ge -\log(x) -\frac{1}{x}(y-x) &=-\log(x) - \frac{y-x}{x}\\ &= -\log(x) - \frac{y}{x} + 1
\end{align*}
Hence
\begin{align*}
-\log(y) &\ge  -\log(x)- \frac{y}{x} + 1\\
\implies \sum_{i,j}\Big(-\log(y)\Big)  &\ge\sum_{i,j}\Big( -\log(x)- \frac{y}{x} + 1\Big)\\
\implies \sum_{i,j}b_{ij}\Big(-\log(y)\Big)  &\ge\sum_{i,j}b_{ij}\Big( -\log(x)- \frac{y}{x} + 1\Big)
\end{align*}
We can substitute $x = \theta_i^t + \theta_j^t$ with the previous estimate and $y = \theta_i + \theta_j$. We get
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i,j}b_{ij}\Big(-\log(\theta_i + \theta_j)\Big)  &\ge\sum_{i,j}b_{ij}\Big( -\log(\theta_i^t + \theta_j^t)- \frac{\theta_i + \theta_j}{\theta_i^t + \theta_j^t} + 1\Big)\\
\underbrace{
\sum_{i,j}b_{ij}\Big(\log(\theta_i)-\log(\theta_i + \theta_j)\Big)}_{f(\theta)} &\ge\underbrace{\sum_{i,j}b_{ij}\Big(\log(\theta_i) -\log(\theta_i^t + \theta_j^t)- \frac{\theta_i + \theta_j}{\theta_i^t + \theta_j^t} + 1\Big)}_{g(\theta|\theta^t)}\tag{1}
\end{align*}
Notice that the objective now is separable w.r.t. the parameters $\theta_i$, so we need to maximize
$$
\sum_{j \ne i}b_{ij}\log(\theta_i) - \sum_{j \ne i}\theta_i^t(b_{ij} + b_{ji})/(\theta_i^t + \theta_j^t)\tag{2}
$$ 
w.r.t. $\theta_i$ for every $i$. We can put this in the form of $a \log (\theta_i) - \theta_i$ , where $a>0$. Because this function is concave, setting the derivative to zero (at $\theta_i = a$) yields the global optimum. The next estimate is therefore
$$
\theta_i^{t + 1} = a = \frac{\sum_{j\ne i}b_{ij}}{\sum_{j\ne i}(b_{ij} + b_{ji})/(\theta_i^t + \theta_j^t)}\tag{3}
$$
**My questions**

- Is the derivation up to equation (1) correct?
- What are the exact steps to go from (1) to (2)?
- What are the exact steps to go from (2) to (3)?